# No funciona input file al cargar página con AJAX

Tags: ajax, input

Cargo una página en un div mediante AJAX.
Esa página tiene un campo input file. La carga está ok.
Pero al hacer click en el botón "Examinar" no abre la ventana para seleccionar el archivo.
Agradezco sugerencias,
Este es mi código:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".cargarcobranzasxls", function(e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    
        $.ajax({
            url: "c_agregarcobranzas_xls.php", 
            success: function(data){
            $(document).find('#detallesdepedido').html(data) 
            },
            error: function(data){
            $(document).find('#detallesdepedido').html(data) 
            }
        }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="cargaxlsformulario" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

<input id="file-upload" type="file" style='display: block;' accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel"/>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar"> 

</form>
```

Comment: Me he permitido editar la pregunta, creando un code snippet correcto y **agregando la librería jQuery**. Como podrás ver si pulsas en `Ejecutar` el input file funciona. Si no funciona en tu contexto es porque no estás incluyendo jQuery o por otro motivo. Revisa la consola del navegador en tu contexto para ver si hay errores en ella.

Answer (score 0):

Hay algo más en el código? Ese código me esta sirviendo correctamente. Lo puedes ver
[aquí](https://codepen.io/lleoz/pen/LYxzyva)

Comment: Esto parece más un comentario que una respuesta en si